Short story in which a man sends his mind back in time to change the outcome of a battle, leading to unintended consequences
Trying to find a short story, read ca. 1989.
A man, angry over a past infantry battle with artillery raining down, signs up for a trip back to "fix" things - somewhat like PKD's "We Can Remember It For You Wholesale." Wired into a machine and sent back, he arrives in a modern attack aircraft and strafes the enemy lines. He then watches in horror as enemy artillery, no longer restrained by the proximity of their own troops, moves closer and completely destroys the friendly lines. Back in the present, the man is spattered all over the walls of the room.

Doesn't sound related to ""We Can Remember It For You Wholesale". Maybe a different PKD?
